# Getting ImageView to middle of RelativeLayout - Android

Tags: android, layout

I have been having trouble getting this LinearLayout to move to the vertical center of the RelativeLayout which is it's parent. I have tried many methods and maybe I am using the wrong one but I am not sure. Can someone just check it over to see what I need to add. Thanks. There is some TextViews to the right of the LinearLayout but I didn't include them as you don't require them but just remember the layout needs to be in the vertical center of the RelativeLayout and not in the complete center.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_card"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"      
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/thumb"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to center vertically a element inside a `RelativeLayout`, in your particular case the `LinearLayout`, then add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` attribute to the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

first of all using linear inside relative is not a good idea, i prefer u change that but still if u wanna keep it same, cannot move linear layout in middel, u have to move ur image

now there are many ways such as

`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

plus you can give margin -inputs manually

`android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
    android:layout_marginleft="80dp"`..

try these first, but still strongly recommend to use either Linear or Relative and u can always drag ur UI's in design view.

Comment: I have to use two different layouts as I have different background xml files for each. Now I am wondering whether I could do without one of the drawable xml files

Comment: yes, u can but the basic idea is to keep them same at.. the very start i.e either relative or Linear.., but yes like u did just now u can use relative and u can adjust ur UI's by using `android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"` these and them  manually dragging them or giving margin...